# What should I do after cross validation?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I use `cross_validate` in my dataset and I don`t understand what this result means:

```
{'fit_time':    array([1.63223672, 1.6485312 , 1.68074203]), 
 'score_time':  array([0.45177341, 0.45384407, 0.45946956]), 
 'test_score':  array([-0.82856214, -0.85846901, -0.79999181]), 
 'train_score': array([-0.72827572, -0.72522363, -0.74185422])}
```

How do I know what is the values predicted? Do I need to use `fit` in `cross_validate` too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These values only show you how good your model did perform based on the given dataset an splits.
By default you are splitting the set 3 times with `cross_validate()`, so you train 3 models (with 3 different parameters)
if you want to return the model parameters from cross validation you need to set `return_estimator=True`

```
tree = DecisionTreeClassifier()
cv_results = cross_validate(tree, X, y, cv=3,
                        return_train_score=False, return_estimator=True)

estimators = cv_results['estimator']
```

With `estimators` being a list containing your fitted models.

now you can return your predicted values of your i'th model with `estimators[i].predict(X)` with i being in range from 0 to cv